# Can I combine multiple parameters in a request to a single argument to the controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to consume a request which I'm not in control of. When the client posts an array `['a', 'b', 'c']` as `x`.

What I actually receive is:
`?x.0=a&x.1=b&x.2=c`

I think the correct encoding of that is `?x=a&x=b&x=c` but as mentioned I'm not in control of the request.

Is there some sort of interception I can do to fix up my `x.index` request into the expected encoding? I've tried writing a `Converter` but I could only persuade that to map a single parameter into another type.

Comment: You can provide the request parameter along with url. It looks like you need matrix params. If that is the case, you can implement.

Comment: There is no canonical HTTP standard for posting an array. So, if you do, the format used will be entirely up to the library you chose to use. As for intercepting, you could use a servlet filter to modify the request's parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement your own [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/06/spicy-spring-inject-custom-method-argument-spring-mvc/) and bind the `x` parameter from [`HttpServletRequest`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object. Take a look at: [How to implement custom parameter mapping in Spring MVC](https://codeboje.de/spring-mvc-argument-mapping-basics/).

If it's a single endpoint that handles the strange parameter convention it would be more readable to just have `HttpServletRequest` as method parameter and do the work there before calling service.

Honestly I'd rather force the client to change the request structure. It doesn't look like a valid syntax for passing array with GET.

Comment: >*Honestly I'd rather force the client to change the request structure.*
Totally agree with you. Unfortunately it's not possible. It's not cooperative.

Comment: @Aswan consider keeping hacks like that in one place, maybe a new gateway type micro-service for mapping client format. Don't let it pollute multiple places if you can avoid it.